# Definitions of absolute and essential Borel space?

Tags: general-topology, borel-sets

All spaces are separable metrizable.

My first question will be about the Borel class $F_\sigma$, but I really want to know if they generalize for all Borel types ($F_\sigma$, $G_\delta$, $F_{\sigma\delta}$, $G_{\delta\sigma}$, etc.)

**1.** Does "$X$ is an absolute $F_{\sigma}$-space" usually mean the same thing as "$X$ is an $F_{\sigma}$-space"?  And does this mean $X$ is an $F_\sigma$-subset of every metric space in which it is embedded? If so, then $F_\sigma$-spaces would be precisely the $\sigma$-compact spaces.

**2.** What is the definition of "$X$ is an essential $F_{\sigma\delta}$-space"? Does this mean $X$ is an $F_{\sigma\delta}$-space but does not belong to any lower class in the hierarchy, e.g. $X$ is neither an $F_\sigma$-space nor a $G_\delta$-space?

Comment: I have never heard of these terms. It would be good if you write down all the definitions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I do not know the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

A space $X$ is an absolute Borel set of class (type) $K$ (e.g. $F_\sigma$) iff whenever we embed $X$ into a metric space $M$ via a homeomorphic embedding $i :X \to M$, $i[X]$ is of that class $K$ in $M$. This notion is due to Kuratowksi, see [this more recent paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0d72/1d641ca4537c9123bacf82757f7de4201778.pdf) for a reference.

- an absolutely closed set is compact, as is easily seen, and an absolute $F_\sigma$ is a $\sigma$-compact space.
- an absolute $G_\delta$ is completely metrisable (also a classic fact).

Absolute $F_{\sigma\delta}$ and $G_{\delta\sigma}$ spaces are more complex, e.g. see the aforementioned paper e.g. , also see [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-04/S0002-9939-1962-0138088-4/S0002-9939-1962-0138088-4.pdf) by Stone.

As to the "essential" part, your hypothesis on its meaning (of that absolute class but no simpler one) makes sense; I could not find an authorative reference for it, though.